# Custom stylesheet in GWT RichTextEditor

Tags: gwt

is there a way to force the GWT's RichTextEditor to use custom stylesheet for the edited text?
From what i have seen, it uses an iframe to render the text, so the host documen's styles are ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's currently not possible (there's an [open issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=1052&q=RichTextArea) about it).

As a workaround you could manually add your style definitions to the head element of the iframe document. See [here](http://osdir.com/ml/GoogleWebToolkit/2009-02/msg01016.html) for an example.